# Unsigned (>>>) right shift for byte array

Tags: java, binary, byte, bitwise-operators

I have a byte array of multiple strings. I am replacing one of the strings with a new string whose length is more. Now how can i move the stuff after my concerned string by difference of lenth.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a byte array of multiple strings". Please post code, what you have tried and why it doesn't work, with example inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you mean is that you have a byte array where you have encoding multiple strings into.  You want to replace one of these strings with a longer string.  Unless you have space at the end of the byte[] for such a situation, you will need to create a new byte[].  Copy everything up to the point you want to keep, the string you want to update and then everything after it.

You can use System.arraycopy() to copy to a new byte[] or move bytes around in a byte array.